# Issue with Composer Autoload

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload

I'm kinda new to Autoload Composer, but hopefully I got the composer concept right: Basically you hand over some basic information (composer.json) and the composer then generates the classes which you have to include and then do the work you wanted. Right?

Well, after hours of trying to setup an Autoload Composer, that's my result:

Composer.json:

```
    "name": "lordrazen/dpgenerator",
    "description": "Page to generate Datapacks out of Rawfiles",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "GPL",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "LordRazen",
            "email": "something@gmail.com"
        }
    ],
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "require": {},
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {"Inc\\": "inc/"}
    }
}
```

Class "Test.php" inside the folder "Inc"

```
namespace Inc;

class Test {

}
```

Index.php

```
if (file_exists(dirname(__FILE__) . '/vendor/autoload.php')) {
        require_once (dirname(__FILE__) . '/vendor/autoload.php');
    }

    $test = new Test();
```

I also went to the projects directory in the console and hit "composer update" command.

Well... it still doesnt work:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Test' not found in [...]/index.php:34 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in [...]/index.php on line 34

What's my mistake here?

Comment: You said you have the class `Test.php` inside `Inc` or you define in autoloader the namespace `Inc\\` for the folder `inc`. Try to put it in uppercase.

Comment: Have you tried using the proper class name? Is there any class `Test` in your project, **without any namespace**, or did you import that namespace in your `Index.php`?

Answer (score 1):

You have a class Test in a namespace Inc, but you are not using it, when you are instantiating the class. Just append it in the root folder `index.php`, like so:

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$test = new \Inc\Test();
```

Comment: Wait then I might have understood something wrong:

I thought the namespaces are for a "better-to-read" including: Instead of include('path-to-file.php') you can write "use Inc\Folder\Class" if the namespace if set correctly in the Class. 

Beside this, I thought the autoload should avoid the dozens of "use"-annotations on the beginning of the class. Just autoload them once and you can use them without namespace etc - is this wrong?

Comment: The purpose of namespaces is to capsule/group classes together. Think of App/Util/* and App/Config/* . Before namespaces existed, there were long classnames, e.g. App_Config_JsonReader. Namespaces also help to avoid classname collisions. -- The use statement enables you to shorten often used namespace declarations to a simpler alias name (aliasing) and helps with importing, either the whole namespaced class or only specific elements, e.g. a constant or a function. -- Yes, with Autoloading you dont have to require/include anymore. Classnames are mapped to their file(s) and loaded by name.

Comment: Then my missunderstanding was, that I thought after activating the namespaces and autoloading with this here:

```require_once (dirname(__FILE__) . '/vendor/autoload.php');```

You can create new objects just with the classname, but it's the namespace and the classname, right?

```Wrong: new Class();
Right: new Inc\Folder\Class();```

Comment: Yes, exactly! You need both names - a "namespaced classname". It's called a `fully qualified class name`.

Comment: Glad i could help.